# android keeps on restarting with optimizing apps

Tags: cyanogenmod, xiaomi-redmi-note-4g

**Problem:**

It constantly restarts with optimizing apps.

**Some Background:**

- This phone was running on low disk space some days back, which I
  resolved by removing unwanted files.
- Some apps are third party apps installed by downloading from websites.
- I have searched other threads and none seems to be solving my issue.
- I have done a "cache wipe" as well, which didn't solve the issue.
- This has android version 6.
- I am able to run Fastboot and have access to Fill-Z touch recovery.
- I obviously don't want to format (easy solution) this phone as that
  would delete all the data in there.

**Extra resource:**

[vimeo link describing problem](https://vimeo.com/250837733)

If anyone can let me know how can I disable this "Optimizing app" before the start, I'd be glad.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That usually means it has trouble with one app. The `cyanogenmod` tag lets me assume you've got a custom recovery on the device. Boot into that. Hopefully you have either ADB capabilities there, or the recovery includes a file manager (e.g. Aroma; [tag:twrp] has both). Navigate to the tombstone folder (usually `/data/tombstones`) and check the "trace" block of the latest files. I suspect it always mentions the same app/package-name. If so, delete that app's data directory (`/data/data/<package_name>`). Next boot should succeed. // Had that recently myself …

Comment: Note that mean you will lose that app's data as well! // Please let us know if that worked out.

Comment: @Izzy Seems a good suggestion. Unfortunately, I am not that of an expert and my aroma file manager is not working right now. It says no 
 `cwm/aromafm/aromafm.zip` in path'.  Any help on getting that installed would be awesome. I do have `adb` and `fastboot` access but I am not that expert there either.

Comment: `adb shell`, then `cd /data/tombstones`. `ls` lists the contents. Viewing those files on-device would obviously be a bit tricky for you, so the easiest would be pulling them to your computer: `adb pull /data/tombstones tombstones` would pull the entire folder and place it onto your PC. Then investigate with the tools you're familiar with. Having found the culprit, from `adb shell` (as root) `rm -rf /data/data/<culprits-package-name>`. To exit from `adb shell` type, well, `exit` :)

Comment: On rare instances, this could be corruption of the Dalvik/ART cache, possibly even a defective eMMC storage chip. Honestly at this point I would backup any data that is important and clean install (wipe everything). Once of the things anyone on a custom ROM should be prepared to do at any time is wipe all data and reinstall, kind of goes with the whole "custom rom" way of life, so to speak.

Comment: Thanks @Izzy. I was able to resolve the issue by using your suggestion. I tried some extra steps. 
I flashed "Aroma file manager" because that was not installed in my Phill Z recovery. One thing to note was that Aroma File Manager had to be flashed twice(using zip install from external memory); thus it allowed me access to `/data/tombstones` as well as `/data/data/<Package_name>`. I not only removed problematic packages, but also removed some clutter folders which were lying there unused. Viola!
I would want to make this as answer If @Izzy can post this comment as answer. Thanks!

Comment: \o/ Glad I hit the nail with my hammer :) Summed up everything in an answer as requested. Enjoy the revival :) // @acejavelin if it were a corrupted Dalvik/ART cache, the "optimizing apps" should have fixed that: doesn't that rebuild the very same cache? But definitely the backup idea is a good reminder :) And your hint of "being prepared" does not only apply to custom ROMs: being on such one often has another "backdoor" (thanks to root) a "common stock user" does not have …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue not that long ago: the culprit seems to be some app ART cannot compile for some reason. As you successfully applied my solution and confirmed, let me sum up the facts from the comments in an answer:

#### 1. figure which app is the culprit.

On each of those crashes, the Android system sets a "tombstone" on the "grave" of the dying process – something known on Unix/Linux systems as [Core Dump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump). Those core dumps are placed into `/data/tombstones`, with at maximum 10 files kept (after that, the oldest one will be overwritten on the next occasion). So we need to look to those tombstones to see whats written on them. As you have a custom recovery which offers [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) access, the easiest way is:

1. `adb pull /data/tombstones tombstones` (will copy the entire directory to your computer)
2. use a viewer/editor of your choice (best one you are familiar with) to open and investigate each of the tombstones, starting with the newest and walking back.
3. look into the "stack trace" to see if an app (or it's path in `/data/data`) is mentioned there. If so, note it. If it's the same app in the next tombstone and the one after, you can be pretty sure this is the case we're describing here.

#### 2. put the "obstacle" out of ART's way

Having identified the app, we need to remove it so [art](/questions/tagged/art) doesn't get stuck with it. For this, again we need `adb shell` with its [root](/questions/tagged/root) prompt – and the directory name from our tombstones:

```
rm -rf /data/data/<whateveritwas>
```

Note this removes all the data of the app as well – so having a backup in advance might be a good idea (in the current state: either `adb pull` the directory, or do a [nandroid](/questions/tagged/nandroid) backup you can analyze later).

That done, reboot. Now "optimizing apps" should finish successfully.

#### Alternatives to the command-line approach

Some custom recoveries ship with an integrated file manager, usually called "Aroma". Above steps could also be perfomed with that:

- navigate to `/data/tombstones`
- view the tombstones
- navigate to `/data/data` and remove the offender